# What asset details are the most relevant in a cyber security risk assessment procedure?

Tags: risk-management

I am identifying organisation assets for a cyber security risk assessment. I am looking for guides or industry best practices for what asset details are actually useful for the risk assessment procedure.

We can easily get a lot of information on hardware and software assets by running scripts. We will store all of it, because we never know what we might need. However, in the scope of a cyber security risk assessment, some of it will not be useful. For example: I understand that server IP addresses are important security-wise, but motherboard manufacturer and model name are not so much.

**Is there a concrete set of asset details that are most relevant for an asset report for a security risk assessment discussion?**

Or, equivalently,

**Is there a set of asset details that are "too much", that can be safely omitted from the asset report?**

Comment: You can check out Annex B of ISO 27005. I think the majority of your question(s) will be answered there. If not, I can write up an answer later.

Comment: @TomK. Thanks for the info, I looked up ISO 27005 and it is helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are tackling this problem **backwards**. You assess risks against *threats*. The threats inform you of what is relevant.

Is your risk that the hardware has a built-in backdoor from the government of the manufacturer's country? Then, yes, "motherboard manufacturer and model name" are crucial pieces of data.

Gathering tons and tons of data hoping that some piece of it might be useful is not the way to go. Figure out your threats then assess against them. There is no set standard to follow.

Sometimes an expert can help you add to the list of relevant items because they might understand the threats a little better than you do, so do not discount outside help, papers, or reports. That's why Threat Intel is a vital part of a risk process.

Answer (score -1):

Some context would be good here.  Are you wanting to carry out a purely technical assessment across your organisation, or a broader higher level risk assessment? If the former then a vulnerability scan across your network would be a very good place to start, and would identify any large technical risks (unpatched software & vulnerabilities) whilst also providing you with a useable asset inventory.  The fact that you are asking this question suggests this is not already something which is done.

If you want to carry out a broader risk assessment my advice would be to avoid over complication or paralysis by analysis.  If you collect the minutiae of detail then you will be swamped with data and not be able to see the wood for the trees!

So keep the detail high level: OS, network zone (DMZ, LAN, etc), business function, and criticality. Criticality should help you to classify assets from a security perspective.  Look up the CIA triad (Confidentiality, Integrity, Availability) to help you with this. Use a simple classification system, e.g. High, Medium, Low, to classify systems and then assets.  So a system, including all related assets, which stores confidential customer data would be rated High for confidentiality, and one that stores public information, such as track listings for music podcasts, would be rated Low.

Grouping assets by criticality will allow you to focus assessment and remediation activity on the most important assets to your organisation.  You can then look at border controls; is there a patching schedule in place, is vulnerability scanning carried out, is admin access controlled, etc, to identify and assess the gaps that lead to actual risks.  Again this is high level, but if this is the first time your organisation has carried out this activity I can guarantee you that you will discover enough to keep you busy for quite some time!

One word on threat: Yes it comes into it, and if your organisation is mature from a cyber perspective, then using threat analysis can help. But for mere mortals, using control frameworks, like the CIS CSC 18, which already take common threats into account, can fast-track that whole complicated area.

Comment: CIS is only 18 controls now

Comment: You spent a lot of time on this answer, but only two sentences actually address the question. And you repeat what the OP already concedes (that there can be too much detail). After that, you spend 60% of your answer falling down the rabbit hole of defining "criticality" and the impact of that, which is not relevant to the question asked.